# Laravel - Authentication returns "Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous" because a JOIN in a GlobalScope

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm having a trouble with the Laravel Authentication. When I make a login, Laravel returns the error: "Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous" because I have a GlobalScope that has a JOIN.

The Error:

```
Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `playables` as `p` on `users`.`id` = `p`.`user_id` inner join `league_of_legends` as `lol` on `p`.`playable_id` = `lol`.`id` and `p`.`playable_type` like '%LeagueOfLegends%' where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`banned` = 0 limit 1)
```

Login Code:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

Global Scope:

```
$builder->join('playables as p', 'users.id', '=', 'p.user_id')
        ->join('league_of_legends as lol', function ($join) use ($game){
            $join->on( 'p.playable_id', '=', 'lol.id');
            $join->on('p.playable_type', 'like', DB::raw( "'%$game%'"));
});
```

I tried to rename the primary key of model User but this cased others errors. There is an alternative? Or I have to use Local Scopes??

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `$primaryKey = 'users.id'` in your `Users` model?

Comment: Yes, I tried. How I said on the question: "I tried to rename the primary key of model User but this cased others errors". :/

Comment: @RegisZanandrea Adding `$primaryKey = 'users.id'` to your User model didn't affect the resulting query? This is not the same as renaming the column itself.

Comment: This works, but this cased others errors. Like User::find(2) : "Column not found users.user.id".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eloquent Builder like me, the solution was to specify the primary key name on the model with the global scope:

```
protected $primaryKey = "users.id";
```

Answer (score 1):

`Builder` store it's `where` clauses publicly in array as `$builder->wheres`.

So you can access and modify the variable. But only for this time because it's not the correct way, obviously.

The current `$builder->wheres` is like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["type"]=> string(5) "Basic"
        ["column"]=>  string(2) "id"
        ["operator"]=> string(1) "="
        ["value"]=>  string(1) "1"
        ["boolean"]=> string(3) "and"
  }
  // ... Others are array of column deleted_at and banned
}
```

So just loop the `$builder->wheres` and modify it as

```
foreach( $builder->wheres as $key => $item ){
    // Only modify column of 'id'
    if( $item['column'] == 'id' ){
        $builder->wheres[$key]['column'] = 'users.id';
        break;
    }
}
```

You can put second `join` clause as `where` clause

```
$builder->join( 'league_of_legends AS lol', function( $join ){
    $join->on( 'p.playable_id', '=', 'lol.id');
})->where( 'p.playable_type', 'LIKE', DB::raw( "'%$game%'") );
```

Finally do `select` for users

```
// This also reset the SQL SELECT that previously defined
$builder->select( 'users.* AS users' );
```

So it will be

```
foreach( $builder->wheres as $key => $item ){
    // Only modify column of 'id'
    if( $item['column'] == 'id' ){
        $builder->wheres[$key]['column'] = 'users.id';
        break;
    }
}

$builder
    ->select( 'users.* AS users' )
    ->join( 'playables AS p', 'users.id', '=', 'p.user_id' )
    ->join( 'league_of_legends AS lol', function( $join ){
        $join->on( 'p.playable_id', '=', 'lol.id');
    })->where( 'p.playable_type', 'LIKE', DB::raw( "'%$game%'") );
```